# how to test spring mvc model attributes from controller that return objects containing objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I have a `controller` that I am trying to test. I am adding myObj as an attributes, where myObj is itself an object as

```
public class MyObj {

private List<OtherObj> otherObjList;
private SecondObj secondObj;
//getter setter

}
```

**here is my controller**

```
  @Controller
    public class MyController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(final Model model) {

           //i prepare myobj here 
            model.addAttribute("myObj",myObj);
            return "myPage";
        }

}
```

**And this is my test case.** I am trying to see if properties inside first item of 
otherObjList is some value or not. This is what i tried but not working

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute("myObj.otherObjList", hasItems(hasProperty("id", is(12345)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to test a normal controller, I think you are on the right track, but the `.` notation won't fit. Have a look at the following sample test assertions:

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("todo/list"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/todo/list.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                        allOf(
                                hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                                hasProperty("description", is("Lorem ipsum")),
                                hasProperty("title", is("Foo"))
                        )
                )))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                        allOf(
                                hasProperty("id", is(2L)),
                                hasProperty("description", is("Lorem ipsum")),
                                hasProperty("title", is("Bar"))
                        )
                )));
```

Maybe this page can help you: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers/

Comment: i have been using jsonPath for my rest controller. This would not work for controller.

Comment: could you please first look my question.Object i am returning is complex.